# Не получается подключиться к удаленной БД postgres

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, pgadmin

Знаю, что тема довольно заезженная, но гугл не помогает.

Настройки на удаленном сервере

**postgresql.conf**

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

**pg_hba.conf**

```
hostssl mydb mydb_admin  0.0.0.0/0  md5
```

С помощью такой команды я подключаюсь к этой базе без проблем:

```
psql -U mydb_admin -h 190.01.01.01 mydb
```

Проблема возникает при попытке подключения через графические админки. Я пробовал через pg_admin3 и через postbird.

Ошибка такая:

> no pg_hba.conf entry for host 188.01.01.01, user mydb_admin, database "mydb", SSL off

188.01.01.01 - ip моего компьютра
190.01.01.01 - ip сервера

Скриншот настроек:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А через `host` вместо `hostssl` соответственно заходит нормально?

Comment: @Denis640Kb Нет, ничего не меняется :(

Comment: @Denis640Kb таки нет, после некоторых плясок с бубном host сработал. Спасибо